# Got both 'component' and 'children' props for the screen 'Search'. You must only pass one of them

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-navigation

I work on a react-native app and this project used react-navigation 4.x to navigate around the app.
I recently upgraded the project to 5.x of react-navigation and while trying to upgrade I ran into a problem. The problem is that my project has both a `FooterNavigator` and a `DrawerNavigator`, they both call on the same component.

We already figured out a way to fix the problem in react-navigation 4.x but the new version of react-navigation requires a name and a component for each `Screen`. Is there any way for me to have both the navigators at the same time or is it better to downgrade?

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFXqE.png)

This is my FooterNavigator

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

    export const FooterNavigator = () => {
        return (
                <Tab.Navigator>
                    <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={Search}>
                        <Button>
                                <Icon name="magnify" type="MaterialCommunityIcons"/>
                              <Text style={footerStyle.footerText}>Zoeken</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen name="Count" component={Count}>
                        <Button>
                                <Icon name="counter" type="MaterialCommunityIcons"/>
                                <Text style={footerStyle.footerText}>Tellen</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen name="Identify" component={Identify}>
                        <Button>
                                <Icon name="file-question" type="MaterialCommunityIcons"/>
                                <Text style={footerStyle.footerText}>Herken</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Tab.Screen>
                    <Tab.Screen name="Program" component={Program}>
                        <Button>
                                <Icon name="chip" type="MaterialCommunityIcons"/>
                                <Text style={footerStyle.footerText}>Wijzig</Text>
                        </Button>
                    </Tab.Screen>
                </Tab.Navigator>
        )
    }
```

And this is my DrawerNavigator

```
export const RootNavigator = () => {
    let DrawerScreens = [];
    Routes.forEach(function (route) {
        DrawerScreens.push(<Drawer.Screen name={route.name} component={route.component}/>)
    });
    return (

        <Drawer.Navigator>
            {DrawerScreens}
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    )
}
```

They are both called and rendered in my Layout.js

```
render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <RootNavigator />
                <FooterNavigator/>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
```

Many thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 5):

**use this**

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

**instead of this**

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}> </Stack.Screen>
```

**solve your problem**

```
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: Why does such a minor thing cause an issue? I mean HTML is allowed to have tags either self-closing or having actual closing tags.

Comment: How do you pass props to these components?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove component prop from stack screen. if you are passing custom values through navigation stack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when I use a `<Stack.Screen>` and provide a component and a child to it, as the error mentions.

```
<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}>
        {props => <Home {...props} sampleProperty="XXXXXXXX" />}
</Stack.Screen>
```

removing this bit  `component={Home}` on line1 fixes the error.